# Compiling TypeScript using gulp is creating an unwanted destination folder

Tags: javascript, typescript, gulp

I am trying to get Gulp to transpile my `.ts` files in my `/dev` directory and move the transpiled `.js` file to a `/build` directory.

The desired structure is as follows:

```
/dev
 - index.ts
/build
 - index.js
```

What is actually occuring looks like this:

```
/dev
 - index.ts
/build
 - /dev
    - index.js
```

As you can see the dev folder is being duplicated. The relevant code in `gulpfile.js` is as follows:

```js
var gulp = require('gulp');
var ts = require('gulp-typescript');
var tsProject = ts.createProject('./tsconfig.json');

// gulp ts
gulp.task('ts', function () {
  return tsProject.src('dev/**/*.ts')
    .pipe(ts(tsProject))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build/'));
});
```

I can get my other build tasks to behave in the desired manner but for whatever reason the TypeScript task is giving me grief.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you remove a folder structure when copying files in gulp?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24658011/can-you-remove-a-folder-structure-when-copying-files-in-gulp)

Comment: I do not want to flatten or remove the folder structure but rather maintain it. I want `dev` and `build` to share the same structure.

Comment: I believe you can use gulp.dest callback to modify the file path: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33743973/99256 (i.e. `.pipe(gulp.dest(function(file) {);)`

Comment: @Vizkos I have tried that with the same results. The `.pipe(ts(tsProject))` line is doing something under the hood that I cannot figure out. Commenting out that line maintains the desired structure but obviously does not transpile my files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem. Adding `"rootDir": "dev"` to the compilerOptions in `tsconfig.json` made the gulp task behave as expected.

An unexpected side-effect also occurred and the TypeScript compiler started throwing errors stating that it could not find modules that it previously had no problem finding before. I explicitly added `/// <reference path="../typings/tsd.d.ts" />` to my `.ts` files and was back in business.